# Italian subs and hogies

Tags: flavor

Italian pizza-shop subs that I really like have a very distinctive, long lasting, strong odor. I wonder what this ingredient is??? I use oregano, basil, parsley, red wine vinegar, olive oil, onions, pepper, ham and cooked salami.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in you sub is fairly aromatic.  I would guess that the largest contributors are the salami and the onions, with onions likely being most significant.